# Getting rank based on sum of columns across many categories

Tags: mysql, sum, ranking

I am trying to get the rank of the sum of a column, but also grouped by category.

The table is like this:

```
user_id | category_id | number
   1           1        10.00
   1           1        15.00
   1           2        12.00
   1           2        10.00
   2           1        23.00
   2           1        12.50
   2           2        20.50
   2           2        19.50
   3           1        15.00
   3           1        17.50
   3           2        10.50
   3           2        19.50
```

What I need is to sum the number column and rank by category, and set the limit of results.

So, what I want is to end up with this:

```
 user_id | category_id | total | rank
     2          1        35.50    1
     3          1        32.50    2    
     1          1        25.00    3
     2          2        40.00    1
     3          2        30.00    2
     1          2        22.00    3
```

In this example I am showing the top 3 rankings.

Comment: You sample result set data does not correspond to the sample input. It's really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The sample data has the sum of the number column, per user, per category, and is ranked by that sum. I will update the examples to be a more precise representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `GROUP BY` clause to get sum of `number` per `user_id`, `category_id`:

```
SELECT user_id, category_id, SUM(number) AS total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id, category_id
```

To get rank by category you can use variables and apply them to the above query as follows:

```
SELECT user_id, category_id, total,       
       @rn := IF (@cat = category_id,
                 IF (@cat := category_id, @rn + 1, @rn + 1),
                 IF (@cat := category_id, 1, 1)) AS rank
FROM (                 
   SELECT user_id, category_id, SUM(number) AS total
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY user_id, category_id ) AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @cat := 0) AS var   
ORDER BY category_id, total DESC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42f7a/2)

If you want to filter the results by rank and display only the top 3 rankings then you can wrap the above in a sub-query and use an outer query:

```
SELECT user_id, category_id, total, rank
FROM ( ... above query here ...) AS s
WHERE s.rank <= 3
```